# t-test on two variance calculations

Tags: anova, variance, t-test

I have survey data that was recorded in a many different towns. I want to see for which variables is the data significantly more or less variable *within towns* than *across all towns*.

Currently, I'm thinking of conducting a Welch's t-test (for samples with unequal variance) on the difference between $\bar{X}_{1} =$ the mean of town-level variances and $\bar{X}_{2} =$ the variance of all observations.

The t-test formula is:

$$ t = \frac{\bar{X}_{1}  -   \bar{X}_{2}  }{     \sqrt{\frac{s_{1}^{2}}{n_{1}}  +\frac{s_{2}^{2}}{n_{2}}    }  } $$

Is this the right approach? I'm not sure if the t-test is right, and even if the t-test is right am I calculating the variance of variances correctly? I also wonder if there is a better way to approach this using ANOVA.  In particular, I'm confused by the fact that in this test $\bar{X}_{i}  = s_{i}^{2}$, which seems strange to me.

Comment: Why not do an explicit test for equality of variances, such as Levene's test?

Comment: @jona thank you for the suggestion! I've barely seen Levene's before so bear with me! I'm curious, Levene's test compares the variances of two sub-samples. Will the test work in my situation where one variance is the average of sub-sample variances from the other group? It seems like Levene's might assume two separate sub-samples, where $X_{1} \cap X_{2} = \varnothing$.

Comment: You want a [Model II anova](http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statanovamodel.html)

Comment: @RayKoopman Thanks Ray, but is that right? I don't care about the null hypothesis that all towns have the same true mean. I care about identifying which variables have a significantly smaller town-level variance than overall population variance. In other words, I want to know which variables are the most homogeneous at the town-level relative to the overall population.

Comment: @DTRM - Click the [partition the variance](http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statanovapart.html) link in the "Model II anova" section of the page I linked you to.

Comment: Related to Ray's advice, see [Bryk and Raudenbush (1988) *Heterogeneity of variance in experimental studies: A challenge to conventional interpretations*](http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/mike/5030/articles/brykraudenbush.pdf)